# Cannot Pick Up Package with Forge Console

Tags: jsf, jboss, console, package, jboss-forge

I can't pick up any packages of my project with Forge Console. I can show every package of every project in force but this one. Is there any way to debug this? Is there an issue with my package architecture?

Error message:

```
  pick-up C:\Users\mememe\workspace\mProject\src\main\java\mProject\model
org.jboss.forge.parser.ParserException: Could not find type declaration in Java source - is this actually code?***ERROR*** Exception encountered: (type "set VERBOSE false" to disable stack traces)

    at org.jboss.forge.parser.spi.JavaParserImpl.parse(JavaParserImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.forge.parser.spi.JavaParserImpl.parse(JavaParserImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.forge.parser.spi.JavaParserImpl.parse(JavaParserImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.forge.parser.spi.JavaParserImpl.parse(JavaParserImpl.java:52)
    at org.jboss.forge.parser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:54)
    at org.jboss.forge.resources.java.JavaResource.getJavaSource(JavaResource.java:143)
    at org.jboss.forge.spec.javaee.rest.RestApplicationFacetImpl$1.visit(RestApplicationFacetImpl.java:120)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet$1.accept(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:293)
    at org.jboss.forge.resources.AbstractResource.listResources(AbstractResource.java:123)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.visitSources(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:286)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.access$000(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:43)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet$1.accept(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:290)
    at org.jboss.forge.resources.AbstractResource.listResources(AbstractResource.java:123)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.visitSources(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:286)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.access$000(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:43)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet$1.accept(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:290)
    at org.jboss.forge.resources.AbstractResource.listResources(AbstractResource.java:123)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.visitSources(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:286)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.access$000(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:43)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet$1.accept(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:290)
    at org.jboss.forge.resources.AbstractResource.listResources(AbstractResource.java:123)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.visitSources(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:286)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenJavaSourceFacet.visitJavaSources(MavenJavaSourceFacet.java:273)
    at org.jboss.forge.spec.javaee.rest.RestApplicationFacetImpl.findApplicationClass(RestApplicationFacetImpl.java:109)
    at org.jboss.forge.spec.javaee.rest.RestApplicationFacetImpl.isInstalled(RestApplicationFacetImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.BaseProject.registerFacet(BaseProject.java:153)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.registerSingleFacet(ProjectFactory.java:208)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.registerSingleFacet(ProjectFactory.java:186)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.registerFacets(ProjectFactory.java:178)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.findProjectRecursively(ProjectFactory.java:117)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.project.ProjectInitializer.doInit(ProjectInitializer.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:198)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:282)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:234)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:635)[no project] dao $ 
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:628)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:75)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.project.CurrentProject.setCurrentResource(CurrentProject.java:80)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.ShellImpl.setCurrentResource(ShellImpl.java:1239)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.ShellImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.setCurrentResource(ShellImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.plugins.builtin.PickupResourcePlugin.run(PickupResourcePlugin.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.command.Execution.perform(Execution.java:134)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.command.fshparser.FSHRuntime.run(FSHRuntime.java:109)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.command.fshparser.FSHRuntime.run(FSHRuntime.java:47)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.ShellImpl$ExecutorThread.run(ShellImpl.java:818)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.ShellImpl.execute(ShellImpl.java:841)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.ShellImpl.doShell(ShellImpl.java:631)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.ShellImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doShell(ShellImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:198)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:282)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:234)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:635)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:622)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:616)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.Bootstrap$1.run(Bootstrap.java:172)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: thx for the upvote. actually I solved this...somehow. Must have been related to my project structure or whatever, I don't really remember.

Comment: Like to know how you managed to fix it

Comment: like I said...no idea. I guess I reinstalled my ide or I created a new project scructure. Maybe I used maven or eclipse to fix my project...